# Heroku add on ever deploy -Dspring.profiles.active=prod

Tags: spring-boot, heroku, dyno

I have 3 application.yml one for dev and one for prod
application.yml (default set to dev)
application-dev . yml
application-prod . yml

When running this command - Dspring.profiles.active=prod it will use my production, how am I able to get this working in heroku?

[image]
Already tried adding -- spring.profiles.active and - Dspring.profiles.active but both are not recognized is there something that i'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars)

```
heroku config:set SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod
```

You can also add it in the Heroku Dashboard (key-value)